# Flyway 2.1, MySQL fails with "was not locked with LOCK TABLES"

Tags: mysql, flyway

Moving from Flyway 2.03 to 2.1, on a MySQL 5.6 database, the Flyway schema update works fine, but then whenever my application tries to run a query (via stored procedure) it fails with "Table 'SomeTable' was not locked with LOCK TABLES". Trying again, it continues to fail, but rolling back to version 2.03 it works fine again.

So, did I miss something I need to update for the new version, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is a bug, caused by this [commit](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/commit/ceb4bbb4f49e802fc76e370c1af069bddae3380b).

I created an issue [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/176)

When using the MySQL command LOCK TABLES it expects a UNLOCK TABLES afterwards, which isn't being issued by flyway. Hopefully it will be fixed soon, as version 2.1 is basically unusable with MySQL.

However, if you go back to version 2.0.3, you should have no problems.

Comment: Thanks, looks fine in 2.1.1!